# Install Powershell in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, powershell

I'm trying to install Powershell in Ubuntu 17.04 as the following these steps:

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y powershell
```

I know I'm using 16.04 packages/built to install. Unfortunately I couldn't find the the 17.04 one.

And here is what error I've got with `sudo apt-get install -y powershell`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
  powershell : Depends: libicu55 but it is not installable
```

Then I tried:

```
apt-cache search libicu
```

I couldn't find out the libicu55 to install either. Are there any way to install Powershell in Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: You should probably wait for MS to release packages for 17.04

Comment: I really don't wanna down vote your question!. But you are talking 2 different things here.  PS is PS, Terminal is Terminal most of the time you can do on both. But for some specific tasks, ofc you can't. For example: if you wanna do LDAP query to AD Server, PS has it own API (modules) to do it ( Ad cmdlets) and also there is possibility to combine PS with .NET, you might be able to do it in Terminal but this is pain is the azz. Generally, they are serving for different approaches :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download the [AppImage](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.5/PowerShell-6.0.0-beta.5-x86_64.AppImage) version and follow the [instructions](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#linux-appimage):

> Using a recent Linux distribution, download the AppImage PowerShell-6.0.0-alpha.18-x86_64.AppImage from the releases page onto the Linux machine.
>
> Then execute the following in the terminal:
>
> ```
> chmod a+x PowerShell-6.0.0-beta.5-x86_64.AppImage
> ./PowerShell-6.0.0-beta.5-x86_64.AppImage
> ```
>
> The AppImage lets you run PowerShell without installing it. It is a
>   portable application that bundles PowerShell and its dependencies
>   (including .NET Core's system dependencies) into one cohesive package.
>   This package works independently of the user's Linux distribution, and
>   is a single binary.

Comment: Worked like a charm! This solved my issue with PowerShell, Windows 10, and Ubuntu WSL.

Answer (score 13):

Download `libicu55` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/amd64/libicu55/download

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
```

If the sudo apt install fails, download the file directly from the provided link via the browser. Then open it with Software Install.

Then follow [instructions for 16.04](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#installation-via-package-repository---ubuntu-1604)

```
...
sudo apt install -y powershell
```

Source: https://asknicks.blogspot.ru/2017/05/install-powershell-on-ubuntu-17.html

Comment: Package libicu55 updated to libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft do not have packages for 17.04 yet. [Take a look at their github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell):

[image]

The problem you have is their package relies on `libicu55`, but 17.04 does not have that package [in its repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libicu55). Unless you [build from source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/building/linux.md), you will not be able to install their public Powershell packages.

Comment: The AppImage from this list will run on most Linux systems including Ubuntu 17.04. To find out more about how this works, visit http://appimage.org/.

Comment: That's a really interesting way of running it, which I didn't know existed before. Thanks for raising it.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the official Microsoft [PowerShell Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/#pivot=main&panel=getstarted) webpage and click the link to visit [PowerShell on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) or visit it directly. There you will find links to download PowerShell .deb files for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and 17.04.

Download the PowerShell .deb file and double-click it to open it in the software application.

---

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

PowerShell can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install the PowerShell Core snap package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install powershell --classic
```